# Terminating threads by interrupting them- java 6

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been working on an application (java-6) where I am required to terminate a thread on form submit.
The application handles several request, each has its "Terminate me" button, the user hits the button, I get the thread id, and I flag the thread interrupted.

I used to have a frequently called part of the code (Logging) where I regularly checked whether  `CurrentThread` was flagged and if yes it threw a `RunTimeException`. That was the way how I used to be able to terminate threads. Unfortunately this part has been removed due to refactoring and now I can't find an appropriate place that is frequent enough to check whether `currentThread` is flagged or not.

A different approach would be somehow to 'force' the threads to regularly check *their own state* (and throw an exception if they are flagged as interrupted). It would be fairly easy if every thread were written by me either by extending `Thread` or implementing `Runnable`, but it is not the case. Is there a way to do it (maybe in Java 7) to 'normal' threads?

Comment: nope, there really isn't.  if you don't control the code, you can't force the thread to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Threads are cooperative by design (unless you want to use the deprecated `stop()` method - it has been deprecated for good reason).

So if a thread doesn't cooperate in it's death, there is little that you can do. There are a couple of methods which check the interrupted flag and throw an `InterruptedException`.

But unless you handle the exception correctly (it clears the flag and you need to set it again if you can't handle it), the flag is easily lost.

You need to change the code to re-introduce the checks. If they won't let you change the code, then I know a couple of tricks to have your way (like replacing the class file in the JAR with a fixed version in the build). But in the end, you really have to change the source.